# Azure ConstraintRules not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, autoscaling

I am deploying a very simple Azure cloud service.

Trying to get Autoscaling working so I can schedule scaling up/down depending on time of day.

Have everything installed and configured, deploys to Azure without any issues however my rules don't seem to be being adhered to.

Currently I have the following, which I would expect service to run at a minimum of 2 instances but it always stays at 1.

```
<rules xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2011/entlib/autoscaling/rules" enabled="true">
  <constraintRules>
    <rule name="Default" description="Default rules" enabled="true" rank="1">
      <actions>
        <range min="2" max="8" target="MyRoleName"/>
      </actions>
    </rule>
  </constraintRules>
</rules>
```

Feel like I'm missing something really simple but unsure what?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

AFAIR from my Wasabi experience - constraint rules without timetable will not be run by service at all - they have no dedicated trigger conditions. It purpose is to limit max and min number of instances - so reactive rules will not be able to over-provisioning (this could lead to higher-than-planned expenses) and under-provisioning  your service instances (this could lead to Azure SLA requirements violation).

I think you should [read this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680945%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx#sec30) about proper way to setup schedule-based autoscaling for your service.
In short - you need timetable section for you rule. Something like that (shameless rip from mentioned link)

```
<rules xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2011/entlib/autoscaling/rules" enabled="true">
  <constraintRules>
    <rule name="Default" description="General Limitation" enabled="true" rank="1">
      <actions>
        <range min="2" max="8" target="MyRoleName"/>
      </actions>
    </rule>

    <rule name="Peak" description="Active at peak times" enabled="true" rank="100">
      <actions>
        <range min="4" max="4" target="MyRoleName"/>
      </actions>
      <timetable startTime="08:00:00" duration="02:00:00">
        <daily/>
      </timetable>
    </rule>
  </constraintRules>
</rules>
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey will take a look now

Comment: Still no luck unfortunately! :(

Comment: Can you provide code sample you are using to launch wasabi. Do you have any error logs ? Maybe you have issues with certificate ? If you want - you can contact me on email centur@gmail.com and we could figure the issue together and after that we will publish solution here for community

Comment: hey alex, i'm working with MS support at the moment. have spent two separate sessions trying to get it working and still nothing! will let you know how i go, appreciate your help - +1'ed all your answers :)

Comment: It will be cool. Probably you could add some kind of default reactive rule which should fire always with lowest priority so the constraint rules will be enforced instead, and this may work, but looks like a hack to me. And you can check Wasabi source code - maybe it will be obvious then :)

Answer (score 0):

Where are you hosting the Autoscaling Application Block? Have you only added the settings file in your question? My answer is that it is not that simple. 
Add a worker role and implement the Autoscaling application block there to handle your web-role.

Old question/answer:You could compare the steps you've done to the following guide/s
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/golive/archive/2012/04/26/auto-scaling-azure-with-wasabi-from-the-ground-up.aspx
and this one is good:
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/autoscaling/

*Without further information it would be really hard to figure out whats not right with your setup.*

Comment: Thanks Magnus have already seen both those but unfortunately neither helped. Should be much easier than this :)